# Django and MongoDB issues with Django admin

Tags: django, mongodb, django-admin, django-nonrel

I'm trying to integrate MongoDB with Django's Admin system ([as per the Tumblelog tutorial on the mongodb site](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/write-a-tumblelog-application-with-django-mongodb-engine/) and hitting a bug when I try to `python manage.py syncdb` - it gives me this error - and I'm not entirely sure what to do about it. Thanks!

```
pymongo.errors.OperationFailure: command SON([('create', u'auth_permission'), ('max', False), ('capped', False), ('size', 0.0)]) failed: exception: create collection invalid size spec
```

```

Answer (score 1):

Seems there is a problem with permission app, Try to add `djangotoolbox` to you `settings.py`.

The nature of NoSQL is not compatible with django ORM neither with `auth`, `permission` apps which they depends on `JOINS` to working together.

Anyway, Have you met [django-nonrel](http://django-nonrel.org/) ? django-nonrel provides more apps and solutions to work with MongoDB and other NoSQL datastores.

Answer (score 1):

See this link: https://github.com/django-nonrel/mongodb-engine/pull/134

The main issue is that for collections that have an uncapped size, set a large capped size instead of  so that the subsequent command does not fail.

I'm assuming you're on django-nonrel 1.3.1. I forked off of django-nonrel/mongodb-engine and have the fix in https://github.com/statguyjames/mongodb-engine.git@master.

Answer (score 0):

First I tried statguy's solution by replacing sql_create_model() method entirely - but it didn't work, some errors kept appearing.

Then what I did was that I added

```
size = getattr(model._meta, 'collection_size', None)
if size is not None:
    kwargs['size'] = size
else:
    kwargs['size'] = 10000000000
```

right after

```
for option, mongo_option in [
        ('capped', 'capped'),
        ('collection_size', 'size'),
        ('collection_max', 'max')
    ]:
        kwargs[mongo_option] = getattr(model._meta, option, False)
```

in file creation.py from django_mongodb_engine.

This way the error wasn't appearing anymore. However, due to that immense value, mongo will allocate some files on disk that have basically turned my current database from a few MB to about 17GB - ending in an error to allocate new file.

So careful about enforcing a value. I might be missing something, though.